# WIndows-10 UWP How to place a button relative to two other button's in Relative Panel

Tags: c#, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I am trying to build Windows-10(UWP) app. My app has 4 buttons which appear at the bottom of the screen.

[image: Screenshot of my app]

Button1, 2 & 4 are in their intended position. I want to place Button3 in between Button2 & Button4. How can I achieve that with RelativePanel in UWP?

My xaml code snippet for Button3 is

```
 <Button Name="BtnTextSearchLaunch" Content="Text Search" RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="Button2" Width="60" Background="#FF291313" Height="30" RelativePanel.RightOf="Button2" >
       <Button.Template>
          <ControlTemplate>
              <Image Source="/Assets/textSearch@2x.png"/>
          </ControlTemplate>
       </Button.Template>
 </Button>
```

I can place Button3 in the required position by specifying the position as in **Margin="a,b,c,d"**, but that doesnt work well if I run the app on mobile. Hence I want to achieve this with RelativePanel, since that would scale the UI dynamically & give me the ability to deploy my app on Local Machine as well as Mobile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
    <RelativePanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <Button x:Name="btn1" Content="btn1" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <Button x:Name="btn2" Content="btn2" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <Button x:Name="btn3" Content="btn3" RelativePanel.RightOf="btn2" RelativePanel.LeftOf="btn4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <Button x:Name="btn4" Content="btn4" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
    </RelativePanel>
</Grid>
```

As you can see from the solution you just need to make sure you place the button relative to both the btn2 and btn4 and don't forget to specify `HorizontalAlignment="Center"`.